# what is called a design pattern similar to factory method which doesn't return an object but calls a method?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

In the factory method, for example if a variable is equal to 5 the creator should return object A, otherwise object B.

I need the name of a design pattern for:
if a variable is equal to 5 the creator should save some data to table A, otherwise it should save other date to table B.

Comment: It's still the factory pattern if the returned objects are callable -- *if a variable is equal to 5 the creator should return object A, otherwise object B; calling object A saves some data to table A, calling object B saves other data to table B*.

Comment: But factory should return an object and in my case it doesn't return object but only call a method.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for the **strategy pattern**?

From *wikipedia*:

In computer programming, the strategy pattern (also known as the policy pattern) is a behavioural software design pattern that enables an algorithm's behavior to be selected at runtime. The strategy pattern:

- defines a family of algorithms
- encapsulates each algorithm
- makes the algorithms interchangeable within that family.